# Error when initializing an object from template class. see reference to class template instantiation

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I know finding errors in code is not something which is done in StackOverflow but I'm posting here because I'm truly desperate as I've been looking for a solution for a while now completely fruitless.

I have a task of implementing my own Stack class (as a linked list). No problem with that part. Here's my code

```
    template<typename T>
struct node {
T inf;
node* link;
};

template <typename T>
class myStack {
private:
node<T> *start;        //Decalration of class myStack. I've left only the default constructor.
public:
myStack();
}

template<typename T>
myStack<T>::myStack() {
start = NULL;
}
```

Everything works as intended. Next part of the task is implementing a queue using two stacks. Basically enqueuing means pushing an element into the first stack, and dequeuing transferring all elements from the first stack to the second and then popping the top one.

Implementation of the queue:

```
template<class T>
class QueueStacks {
myStack<T> stack1;
myStack<T> stack2;

public:
QueueStacks();
void enqueue(T&);
T& dequeue();
void print();
};

template<typename T>
QueueStacks<T>::QueueStacks() { //No need I believe, for default constructor, but I left it for clarity purposes
}


template<typename T>
void QueueStacks<T>::enqueue(T& obj) {
if (stack1.empty()) {
    transferTwoToOne();               //Function transferTwoToOne works as intended, so I didn't deem it necessary to include include its implementation
}
else {
    stack1.push();            //void myStack::push() works as intended, so I deliberately left out its implmentation
}
}

template<typename T>
T& QueueStacks<T>::dequeue() {
T x;
if (stack1.empty() && stack2.empty()) {
    cout << "Attempt to pop from an empty stack";
}
else {
    if (stack2.empty()) {
        transferOneToTwo();                 //Same for function transferOneToTwo
        stack2.pop(x);
    }
    else
        stack2.pop(x);           //same for pop   
    return x;
}
}

template<typename T>
void QueueStacks<T>::print() {
T x;
if (stack2.empty()) {
    transferOneToTwo();
}
while (!stack2.empty()) {
    stack2.pop(x);
    cout << x << " ";
}
}
```

The error comes when I try to initialize an object from class queue. E.g

```
int main()
{
QueueStacks<int> obj1;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    obj1.push(i);
}
obj1.print();
return 0;
}
```

The compiler shows this:note: see reference to class template instantiation 'QueueStacks' being compiled. I got 3 errors:

What am I doing wrong when trying to initialize obj1?

Comment: Create a [mcve] and paste the entire error verbatim

Answer (score 0):

In order to call `push` on `obj1`, the `QueueStacks<int>` would have to have a `push` member function.

Did you mean to invoke `enqueue`?

Comment: Yes, I did mean that. However that is not where the rror come from. In my original code the enqueue fuction was called push, I only changed it to enqueue when creating this post to differentiate between push in the stack and the queue

Comment: After I fixed the typos and added #include directives, it compiled on my machine.  Try to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, then paste the entire error verbatim.

Comment: Found it. In function enqueue, I never pass an argument to stack1.push();